# Overloading operator and modifiyng string

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I am learning about operator overlaoding. I have created simple class to test it.

```
class Beer{
public:
   Beer(int oner , int twor , string name){
   this -> one = oner;
   this -> two = twor;
   this -> name = name;
   };
    int getOne(){

        return this -> one;
    };
    int getTwo(){

        return this -> two;
    };
    string getName(){
        return this -> name;
    };
    Beer operator + (const Beer &a)const {

        return Beer(5,two+a.two,"firstName");

    };
    Beer operator + (string a)const {

       this -> name =  this -> name +" "+a;

    };

private:

   int one;
   int two;
   string name;
};
```

I am trying to figure out , how to midify the string with overloaded operand. My function i declared

```
Beer operator + (string a)const {
      this -> name =  this -> name +" "+a;
};
```

Throws error about passing const string.

I tried using

```
Beer operator + ( const string *a)const { 
       swap(this -> name , this -> name + " " + a);
       return *this;
    };
```

Which complained about one being cosnst string , and secon one being basic string.

The idea is simple.

```
Beer one ( 5, 6, "one")
one + "two"

// one.name = "one two"
```

What is the right way how to do it?

// error with swap

```
error: no matching function for call to 'swap(const string&, std::basic_string<char>)'|
```

// erro with string

```
passing 'const string {aka const std::basic_string<char>}' as 'this' argument of 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>& std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::operator=(std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>&&) [with _CharT = char; _Traits = std::char_traits<char>; _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]' discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]|
```

Comment: Please post the exact compiler errors you get.

Comment: By the way, the semicolon at the end of class method definition is needless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comments:

1. Don't include the entire `std` namespace. You're likely to run into nasty name clashes with your own code. At most, use the symbols you need explicitly, e.g. `using std::string;`.
2. Unless you need a copy of a value to modify, pass large objects like `std::string` by const reference. When you declare a parameter as having a value type `std::string`, you receive a copy of the string, and that's expensive unless you need a copy to modify inside of your function.

   This is a long-standing problem with the C++ standard: an implementation detail like this, that should be irrelevant to the user of the function, leaks into the interface (the declaration of the function). Still, when having a copy makes sense, let the compiler give you one without having to type as much. Thus:

   ```
   // prefer this
   std::string fooize(std::string foo) {
     assert(foo.size() > 0);
     foo.insert(1, "foo");
     return foo;
   }
   // over this
   std::string fooize(const std::string & bar) {
     assert(bar.size() > 0);
     auto foo = bar;
     foo.insert(1, "foo");
     return foo;
   }
   ```
3. Use an initializer list, you then won't need to do silly name gymnastics (you had `oner`, `twor` names:

   ```
   Beer(int one, int two, const std::string & name) :
     one(one),
     two(two),
     name(name)
   {}
   ```
4. Declare read-only accessors const:

   ```
   int getOne() const { return one; }
   ```
5. Return large values like strings by const reference; the user code will likely have the compiler help out with making a copy when needed automatically:

   ```
   const std::string & getName() const { return name; }

   // use:
   Beer beer{0,0,""};
   std::cout << (beer.getName() + "!") << std::endl; // makes a copy of name as needed
   ```
6. In the `+` operator taking a string, you're supposed to return a new object, not modify `this`. You pretty much should do it the way the other operator + you have did it.

   ```
   Beer operator +(const std::string & a) const {
     return Beer(one, two, name + " " + a);
   };
   ```
7. If you want to modify your object, you want `operator +=`:

   ```
   Beer & operator+=(const std::string & a) {
     name += " ";
     name += a;
     return *this;
   }
   ```
8. Even though your class was designed to experiment with operators, you should always consider whether the operators make life easier or not. For example, you class has three members. It's not immediately apparent which of these members would be operated on, unless it was otherwise clear from the class's semantics. It'd be much clearer to have methods named `addToOne`, `addToTwo`, and `appendToName`, for example, instead of operator(s), or simply letting the user set the member through setters, like `setOne(int one) { this->one = one; }`. The user would then simply do `beer.setOne(beer.getOne() + 2);`.
9. Consider naming getters without the `get` prefix, e.g.

   ```
   class Beer {
     int m_one;
   public int one() const { reeturn m_one; }
   };
   ```

   It's less typing for the user. The standard library, as well as large libraries like `boost` and `Qt` follow this convention, e.g. you have `std::string::size()`, not `std::string::getSize()`, etc.

Comment: What is the difference between + and += in this? Why should i use += if i want to modify current object?

Comment: @user3706129 because that is the convention

Comment: @user3706129 Because the `operator +` is expected to create a temporary, and the `operator +=` is expected to modify the existing value. That's how these operators behave on every other sane type, including built-in (e.g. `int`) and standard (e.g. `std::string`). E.g. you can write `1 + 2`, it'd be invalid otherwise as `+` would attempt to modify an rvalue. You can't write `1 += 2`, since `1` isn't an lvalue, as needed by `+=`.

Comment: @user3706129 Of course nobody is stopping you from having any operator do anything at all, but it'll make using your classes rather confusing. Conventions are there for a reason: they make life easier.

Answer (score 1):

```
Beer operator + (string a)const {
  this -> name =  this -> name +" "+a;
};
```

You should not change the contents of the object who's + operator is beeing called, afterall if you perform A = B + C, the contents of B should not change. The compiler is correctly informing you about this because it is a const function.

Rather create a temp object to hold the 'sum' and return it.

```
Beer operator + (string a)const {
    return Beer(one, two, name + " " + a);  
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `operator+()` here:

```
Beer operator+( string a ) const 
{
    this->name = this->name + " " + a;
};
```

the `const` on the function signature is a guarantee to the compiler that when the function is invoked, you won't change the data in the object, yet you change the data in the object.

Comment: I just noticed i left const there , but it throws seg fault without it.

Comment: Don't remove the const, it is correct, see my answer.