# Copy doesn't work in my string::copy implementation

Tags: c++, string, class, oop

Following up on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/126242/23788.

I wrote my string class and according to the feedback I have changed some stuff. Is there anything more that should be fixed?

+operator doesn't work and I do not know what I've done wrong. I have a segfault when I do "Str+Str".

```
Process finished with exit code 139
```

And this is my Str.h

```
class Str {

    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &, Str &);

    friend void swap(Str &s, Str &t) {
        std::swap(s.data, t.data);
        std::swap(s.length, t.length);
        std::swap(s.alloc, t.alloc);
    }


public:
    typedef char *iterator;
    typedef size_t size_type;

    Str() : data(nullptr), length(0), capacity(0) { }

    Str(size_type length, char char_to_fill) : Str() { create(length, char_to_fill); }

    Str(const char *s) : Str() { create(s); }

    template<class In>
    Str(In b, In e) : Str() { create(b, e); }

    ~Str() {
        if (data) alloc.deallocate(data, capacity);
        data = nullptr;
    }

    Str(const Str &s) {
        *this = s;
    }

    // move constructor?
    Str(Str &&other)
            : Str() {// initialize via default constructor, C++11 only
        swap(*this, other);
    }

    Str &operator+=(const Str &s) {
        size_type new_length = length + s.length - 1; //remove 1 because of 2 nulls
        if (new_length > capacity) {
            reallocate(new_length);
            strcpy(data + length - 1, s.data); //overwrite null from s
            length = new_length;
        }
        else {//if there was already enough space
            strcpy(data + length - 1, s.data);
        }
        return *this;
    }

    Str &operator=(Str rhs) {
        swap(*this, rhs);
        return *this;
    }

    char &operator[](size_type i) { return data[i]; };

    const char &operator[](size_type i) const { return data[i]; };

    size_type size() { return length; }

    const size_type size() const { return length; }

    const char *c_str() const {
        return data;
    }

    void copy(char *dest, size_type n) {
        if (n > length)
            throw std::out_of_range("Out of range");
        std::copy(data, data + n, dest);
    }

    char *begin() { return data; };

    char *end() { return data + length; };

    void push_back(char c) {
        if (length == capacity) {
            reallocate(capacity == 0 ? DEFAULT_CAPACITY : 2 * capacity);
        }
        data[length++] = c;
    }

private:
    char *data;
    std::allocator<char> alloc;
    size_type length;
    size_type capacity;
    static const size_type DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 20;

    void create(size_type n, char character_to_fill) {
        capacity = length = n + 1;
        data = alloc.allocate(capacity);
        std::uninitialized_fill(data, data + length - 1, character_to_fill);
        //alloc.construct(data + length - 1, '\0'); //is it needed to be constructed?
        data[length - 1] = '\0';
    }

    void create(const char *s) {
        capacity = length = strlen(s) + 1;
        data = alloc.allocate(capacity);
        strcpy(data, s);
        //alloc.construct(data + length - 1, '\0');
        data[length - 1] = '\0';
    }

    template<class In>
    void create(In b, In e) {
        capacity = e - b + 1;
        data = alloc.allocate(capacity);
        while (b != e) {
            data[length++] = *(b++);
        }
        //alloc.construct(data + length -1, '\0');
        data[length++] = '\0';
    }

    void reallocate(size_t new_capacity) {
        char *new_data = alloc.allocate(new_capacity);
        std::copy(data, data + length, new_data);
        alloc.deallocate(data, length);
        data = new_data;
        capacity = new_capacity;
    }
};

std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &is, Str &s) {
    std::vector<char> buf;
    char actual_character;
    while (is.get(actual_character) && isspace(actual_character)) { ;
    }
    if (is) { //is it correct to check "is" ?
        do buf.push_back(actual_character);
        while (is.get(actual_character) && !isspace(actual_character));
        if (is)
            is.unget();
    }
    s.create(buf.begin(), buf.end());
    return is;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Str &s) {
    os << s.c_str();
    return os;
}

Str operator+(Str lhs, const Str &rhs) {
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

And example main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Str.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
    Str s("Siema");
    cout<<s.c_str()<<endl;

    s = "Hello";
    cout<<s<<endl;

    s.push_back('a');
    cout<<s<<endl;

    Str t = "World";
    //cout<<s+t<<endl; //THIS DOESNT WORK

    s+=t;
    cout<<s<<endl;

    cout<<s[3]<<s[5]<<s[11]<<endl;

    cout<<s.size()<<endl;
    cout<<Str(s.begin()+3, s.end()-2)<<endl;
    for(Str::iterator i = s.begin(); i<s.end() ; i+=2){
        cout<<i<<endl;
    }

    char copied[3];
    t.copy(copied, 4);
    cout<<copied<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code Review and Stack Overflow have very different standards for what constitutes a well-formatted question; please read [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36364191/overloading-operator-and-modifiyng-string/36364394#36364394

Comment: Why is your copy constructor calling the assignment operator, which calls the copy constructor (the parameter is passed by value), which calls the assignment operator, which calls the copy constructor...?  Looks like an infinite loop to me.  Your copy constructor should be written without any assistance from the assignment operator.  Then copy / swap can be used in the assignment operator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code

```
char copied[3];
t.copy(copied, 4);
cout<<copied<<endl;
```

"copied" has only length of 3 while you are trying to copy 4 characters into it. Which will cause problem

Check updated codes below. Read comments with "<--"

str.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>
class Str {

friend std::istream &operator >> (std::istream &, Str &);

 void swap(Str &s, Str &t) {
    std::swap(s.data, t.data);
    std::swap(s.length, t.length);
    std::swap(s.alloc, t.alloc);
}


public:
typedef char *iterator;
typedef size_t size_type;

Str() : data(nullptr), length(0), capacity(0) { }

Str(size_type length, char char_to_fill) : Str() { create(length, char_to_fill); }

Str(const char *s) : Str() { create(s); }

template<class In>
Str(In b, In e) : Str() { create(b, e); }

~Str() {
    if (data) alloc.deallocate(data, capacity);
    data = nullptr;
}

Str(const Str &s) {
    *this = s;
}

// move constructor?
Str(Str &&other)
    : Str() {// initialize via default constructor, C++11 only
    swap(*this, other);
}

Str &operator+=(const Str &s) {
    size_type new_length = length + s.length - 1; //remove 1 because of 2 nulls
    if (new_length > capacity) {
        reallocate(new_length);
        strcpy(data + length - 1, s.data); //overwrite null from s
        //length = new_length;  //<-- You need to update the length anyay. Move it to before return
    }
    else {//if there was already enough space
        strcpy(data + length - 1, s.data);
    }
    length = new_length; //<-- update the length
    return *this;
}

Str &operator=(Str rhs) {
    swap(*this, rhs);
    return *this;
}

char &operator[](size_type i) { return data[i]; };

const char &operator[](size_type i) const { return data[i]; };

size_type size() { return length; }

const size_type size() const { return length; }

const char *c_str() const {
    return data;
}

void copy(char *dest, size_type n) {
    if (n > length)
        throw std::out_of_range("Out of range");
    std::copy(data, data + n, dest);  // <--forgot about '\0'?
    dest[n] = '\0';                   // <-- add '\0'
}

char *begin() { return data; };

char *end() { return data + length; };

void push_back(char c) {
    if (length == capacity) {
        reallocate(capacity == 0 ? DEFAULT_CAPACITY : 2 * capacity);
    }
    data[length++ - 1] = c;  //<-- length - 1 is the last position, because length here includes '\0'
    data[length - 1] = 0;    //<-- don't forget to add '\0'. It's better if you fill the unused spaces to '\0' after allocate them.
}

private:
char *data;
std::allocator<char> alloc;
size_type length;
size_type capacity;
static const size_type DEFAULT_CAPACITY = 20;

void create(size_type n, char character_to_fill) {
    capacity = length = n + 1;
    data = alloc.allocate(capacity);
    std::uninitialized_fill(data, data + length - 1, character_to_fill);
    //alloc.construct(data + length - 1, '\0'); //is it needed to be constructed?
    data[length - 1] = '\0';
}

void create(const char *s) {
    capacity = length = strlen(s) + 1;
    data = alloc.allocate(capacity);
    strcpy(data, s);
    //alloc.construct(data + length - 1, '\0');
    data[length - 1] = '\0';
}

template<class In>
void create(In b, In e) {
    capacity = e - b + 1;
    data = alloc.allocate(capacity);
    while (b != e) {
        data[length++] = *(b++);
    }
    //alloc.construct(data + length -1, '\0');
    data[length++] = '\0';
}

void reallocate(size_t new_capacity) {
    char *new_data = alloc.allocate(new_capacity);
    std::copy(data, data + length, new_data);
    alloc.deallocate(data, length);
    data = new_data;
    capacity = new_capacity;
}
};

std::istream &operator >> (std::istream &is, Str &s) {
std::vector<char> buf;
char actual_character;
while (is.get(actual_character) && isspace(actual_character)) {
    ;
}
if (is) { //is it correct to check "is" ?
    do buf.push_back(actual_character);
    while (is.get(actual_character) && !isspace(actual_character));
    if (is)
        is.unget();
}
s.create(buf.begin(), buf.end());
return is;
}

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &os, const Str &s) {
os << s.c_str();
return os;
}

Str operator+(Str lhs, const Str &rhs) {
lhs += rhs;
return lhs;
}
```

and main:

```
int main() {
Str s("Siema");
cout << s.c_str() << endl;

s = "Hello";
cout << s << endl;

s.push_back('a');
cout << s << endl;

Str t = "World";
//cout<<s+t<<endl; //THIS DOESNT WORK

s += t;
cout << s << endl;

cout << s[3] << s[5] << s[11] << endl;

cout << s.size() << endl;
cout << Str(s.begin() + 3, s.end() - 2) << endl;
for (Str::iterator i = s.begin(); i<s.end(); i += 2) {
    cout << i << endl;
}

char copied[5];  //<-- was 3, not enough space
t.copy(copied, 4);
cout << copied << endl;

return 0;
}
```